# How can I conditionally chain methods in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php code and I was wondering if its possible to conditionally chain methods. I cannot call whereIn if roles is null or empty([]). This works, but is there a cleaner way to do it?

```
 if ($params['roles']){
        $query1 = QB::table('personnel_role')
            ->select(QB::raw('IF(personnel.nickname != "",CONCAT(IFNULL(personnel.first_name,"")," ", IFNULL(personnel.last_name, ""), " (",personnel.nickname,")"), CONCAT(IFNULL(personnel.first_name,"")," ", IFNULL(personnel.last_name,""))) AS "name", personnel.id'))
            ->leftJoin('personnel', 'personnel_role.personnel_id', '=', 'personnel.id')
            ->whereIn('personnel_role.role_id', $params['roles'])
            ->groupBy('personnel.id')->limit($params['skip'])
            ->offset($params['start']);
        }else{
        $query1 = QB::table('personnel_role')
            ->select(QB::raw('IF(personnel.nickname != "",CONCAT(IFNULL(personnel.first_name,"")," ", IFNULL(personnel.last_name, ""), " (",personnel.nickname,")"), CONCAT(IFNULL(personnel.first_name,"")," ", IFNULL(personnel.last_name,""))) AS "name", personnel.id'))
            ->leftJoin('personnel', 'personnel_role.personnel_id', '=', 'personnel.id')
            ->groupBy('personnel.id')
            ->limit($params['skip'])
            ->offset($params['start']);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your queries are essentially the same except for `whereIn`, you can just tack that on by itself in a conditional.

```
$query1 = QB::table('personnel_role')
    ->select(QB::raw('IF(personnel.nickname != "",CONCAT(IFNULL(personnel.first_name,"")," ", IFNULL(personnel.last_name, ""), " (",personnel.nickname,")"), CONCAT(IFNULL(personnel.first_name,"")," ", IFNULL(personnel.last_name,""))) AS "name", personnel.id'))
    ->leftJoin('personnel', 'personnel_role.personnel_id', '=', 'personnel.id')
    ->groupBy('personnel.id')->limit($params['skip'])
     ->offset($params['start']);

if($params['role']) {
    $query1 = $query1->whereIn('personnel_role.role_id', $params['roles']);
}
```

Comment: I'm asking because I'm not sure myself (not sure about what framework this is) - but are you sure that the methods doesn't have to be called in the right order?

Comment: I'm not sure either. Most frameworks I've used don't care about the order.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
$query1 = QB::table('personnel_role')
            ->select(QB::raw('IF(personnel.nickname != "",CONCAT(IFNULL(personnel.first_name,"")," ", IFNULL(personnel.last_name, ""), " (",personnel.nickname,")"), CONCAT(IFNULL(personnel.first_name,"")," ", IFNULL(personnel.last_name,""))) AS "name", personnel.id'))
            ->leftJoin('personnel', 'personnel_role.personnel_id', '=', 'personnel.id');

if ($params['roles']) {
   $query1->whereIn('personnel_role.role_id', $params['roles'])
}

$query1->groupBy('personnel.id')
       ->limit($params['skip'])
       ->offset($params['start']);
```